# AppCompatDelegate Failed to instantiate custom view inflater android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When Getting Release apk am getting this error log in all activities of the app

```
04-03 17:10:54.105 26527-26527/? I/AppCompatDelegate: Failed to instantiate custom view inflater android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater. Falling back to default.
            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater
              at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
              at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
              at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
              at android.support.v7.app.j.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1014)
              at android.support.v7.app.j.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605)
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677)
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1943)
              at android.support.v7.app.j.x(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:374)
              at android.support.v7.app.j.w(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
              at android.support.v7.app.j.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
              at android.support.v7.app.c.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
              at com.myapp.example.MainActivity.I(MainActivity.java:1523)
              at com.myapp.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:358)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
              at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
              at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
              at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
              at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273) 
              at android.support.v7.app.j.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1014) 
              at android.support.v7.app.j.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092) 
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725) 
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605) 
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677) 
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1943) 
              at android.support.v7.app.j.x(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:374) 
              at android.support.v7.app.j.w(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323) 
              at android.support.v7.app.j.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
              at android.support.v7.app.c.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
              at com.myapp.example.MainActivity.I(MainActivity.java:1523) 
              at com.myapp.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:358) 
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010) 
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater
              at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
              at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
              at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                  ... 32 more
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

App Gradle Configuration is given below:

- compileSdkVersion 27,
- buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
- minSdkVersion 16,
- targetSdkVersion 24
- support_library_version = '27.1.0',
- google_play_services_version = '12.0.1'**

Note: Am getting this error only in release build & not in debug build.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write Pro Guard Rules :

`-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }`

Comment: try this :

`-keep class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater{ <init>(...); }`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this is a bug with `appcompat-v7` `27.1.0`: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74289571

> Mar 27, 2018 07:49AM
>
> The development team has fixed the issue that you have reported and it will be available in a future build.

You can either update to a newer version of the support libraries (if this fix has already been released), or downgrade to the previous version where this bug was not present: `27.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use same version for `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `support library`. So, you need to use version **27**:

- `compileSdkVersion 27`
- `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"`
- `targetSdkVersion 27`
- support_library_version = '27.1.0'

Comment: Not the user who asked (but I have the same problem) and I'm already using those versions, so...

Answer (score 0):

I think they fixed this in 27.1.1.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Both by testing it and by looking at the release notes of 27.1.1, I'd say this hasn't been fixed.

Comment: October and still not fixed :)